# On the converse of Schur's Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $F$ a field with $\mathrm{char}(F)=0$ or coprime to $|G|$. Let $V$ be a $FG$-module in a way that every $ FG$-homomorphism $ f : V \to V $ is given by $f(x)= \lambda x $. Then $V$ is irreducible.

I already managed to proof this by contradiction, using Maschke's Theorem. We can  write $V$ as $U\oplus W$ and get a $FG$-homomorphism $\pi:U\oplus W \to U\oplus W$, $\pi (u+w)=u$, then $\pi(u+w)=\lambda (u+w)=u $ then either $U$ or $W$ are trivial and thus $V$ is irreducible.

My question is if this statements still holds if the characterictic of $F$ divides the order of $G$, since I only used this fact in my proof to use Maschke's theorem.

Comment: I think the regular representation of the cyclic group of order $2$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$ is indecomposable, but reducible, with the endomorphism ring equal to $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: Consider the two-dimensional representation of the group of order 2 over the field of order 2, where the nontrivial element is mapped to a matrix with 3 ones and a zero.

Comment: @Batominovski The regular representation has endomorphism ring isomorphic to the group algebra $\mathbb{F}_2[C_2]$, so there are endomorphisms that are not scalar multiples of the identity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are counterexamples in general.

Suppose $V$ is a non-split extension of two non-isomorphic simple modules. I.e., $V$ has a unique simple submodule $W$ with simple quotient $U=V/W$ where $U\not\cong W$. Then any non-zero endomorphism of $V$ is an isomorphism, since the only possible kernel is $W$, but the image can't be $V/W=U$ since $V$ has no submodule isomorphic to $U$. If, further, $U$ and $W$ have $F$ as endomorphism ring, this isomorphism must be a scalar multiple of the identity.

For an explicit example, let $G$ be the group of invertible upper triangular $2\times 2$ matrices over a finite field $F$ with $\vert F\vert>2$, and let $V$ be the natural $2$-dimensional $FG$-module.

Comment: [since $W$ has no submodule isomorphic to $U$] didn't you mean "since $V$" ?

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. Thanks, yes. I’ve fixed it.

Comment: I like your scheme of a bunch of situations where $End(V)$ is a field.

Comment: Sorry to comment on this question years after the fact, but could you elaborate on why your explicit example is actually an example of this? Aren't the elements of $G$ themselves $FG$-homomorphisms?

Comment: @tolUene An $FG$-homomorphism has to commute with the action of every group element, so the action of an element $g\in G$ is not necessarily an $FG$-homomorphism unless $g$ commutes with every other group element (i.e., unless $g$ is in the centre of $G$). In the example, the centre of $G$ consists of scalar multiples of the identity matrix, which all act as multiplication by a scalar.