# Converse of Schur's Lemma in finite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to prove (or disprove) the converse of Schur's Lemma in finite dimensional vector spaces. I am not sure if it holds in this case, but I have tried to apply the idea that proves it in representation theory (see for example Theorem 4.3 [here](https://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjVwNjb783NAhVJJsAKHXqABs0QFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fscipp.ucsc.edu%2F~haber%2Fph251%2Fschur.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFw3sd9Tr427JKLWLhi-iP2NORZvQ&sig2=oyC_2jFrZSy4j1IAHbvZhA) that uses Maschke's theorem or in questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542380/the-converse-of-schur-lemma) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794724/on-the-converse-of-schurs-lemma)).

The converse of Schur's Lemma in finite dimensional vector spaces is:

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the complex numbers. Let $S$ be a set of endomorphisms of $V$ and assume that every endomorphism $A$ of $V$ such that $$AB=BA\text{ for all }B\in S$$ is of the form $\lambda I, \ \lambda\in\mathbb{C}$. Then $V$ is a simple $S$-space.

(*an endomorphism of $V$ is a linear operator from $V$ to $V$

*$V$ is a simple $S$-space if the only $S$-invariant subspaces of $V$ are $V$ itself and the zero subspace)

What I've tried so far:

Assume to the contrary that $V$ is not a simple $S-$space. Then, there exists a subspace $W$ of $V$ such that $W\not =\{0\}$, $W\not= V$ and $W$ is $S$-invariant. Let $W'=V\setminus W$. Then, since $V$ is finite, we can easily prove that $V=W\oplus W'$ (this is my attempt to translate Maschke's theorem in vector spaces). Consequently, for every $v\in V$, there exists unique $w\in W$ and $w'\in W'$, such that $v=w+w'$. Define the projection $P:V\rightarrow V$ by $Pv=w$ for every $v\in V$.

What is left to prove is that $PB=BP$ for all $B\in S$. Then $P$ is clearly not a scalar and thus we have the contradiction we are looking for.

There is a difficulty in showing that $PB=BP$ for all $B\in S$, because $W'$ might be $S$-invariant or not. More precisely:

Let $v\in V=W\oplus W'$ and $v\not =0_V$.

If $v\in W$ then $Bv\in W$ because $W$ is $S$-invariant, therefore: $PBv=Bv$ and $BPv=Bv$.

If $v\in W'$ then $Pv=0$, hence $BPv=B\cdot 0=0$, and

(i) if $Bv\in W'$ then $PBv=0$.

(ii) if $Bv\in W$ then $PBv=Bv$ and this is where the problem occurs.

Any hints, ideas or counterexamples would be very helpful.

Comment: The converse does not hold in general. I need to think more to come up with an elementary example, but at least for algebraic groups in positive characteristic there are plenty of examples.

Comment: Maybe the counterexample we are looking for in vector spaces will involve a subspace $W'$ that is not $S$-invariant.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is also possible to find counter examples that are not indecomposable, by taking a direct sum of two examples with no non-zero homomorphisms between them.

Comment: If you have $BP = PB$ , you might could show that they don't share eigenvectors and that P is not diag, thus they can't commute in general.
IFF $BP = PB \Leftrightarrow 0 = BP - PB \Rightarrow PB\ simultaneously\ triag'bar$ Also you might want to look up McCoy theorem about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a counterexample: let $S = \{A \in \Bbb C^{2 \times 2} : Ax = x\}$ where $x = (1,0)$ (the column-vector $(1,0)$).  That is, $S$ is the set of all matrices whose first column is $(1,0)$.

Now, the span of $(1,0)$ is an $S$-invariant subspace.

However, consider any $A$ that is not a multiple of the identity.  If $A$ is diagonalizable, then it has eigenvectors $y_1,y_2$ with $Ay_i = \lambda_i y_i$. One of these eigenvectors is linearly independent to $x$, suppose WLOG that $y_1$ and $x$ are linearly independent.  We can then define $B$ by
$$
Bx = x\\
By_1 = y_1 + y_2
$$
we find that $ABy_1 \neq BAy_1$, so that $AB \neq BA$.

Now, suppose that $A$ is not diagonalizable.  It follows that $A$ is not diagonal.  So, it fails to commute with 
$$
B = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&2}
$$
Thus, $S$ is a counterexample to your claim.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the closure of the group generated by your two elements is my $S$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen not as an algebra, since mine is not closed under addition or scalar multiplication.  And of course, +1 is appreciated.

Comment: Arrggh. You're right of course.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen technically correct: the best kind of correct

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sorry, I'm confused. Is this a counterexample to the converse? Because in the hypothesis of the converse we have that every commuting matrix is a scalar.

Comment: That's right.  Any matrix $A$ that isn't a scalar matrix fails to commute with *some* element of $S$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Why _some_ element of $S$? I mean, isn't it that: "any matrix that isn't a scalar matrix fails to commute with _every_ element of $S$"? Can you explain the logical argument a bit more because I think I'm missing something.

Comment: What is the logical negation of the statement "$A$ commutes with all elements of $S$"? Is it "For some $B\in S$, $AB \neq BA$", or is it "For every $B \in S$, $AB\neq BA$"?

Comment: The first statement is the negation of what you mentioned, but shouldn't the negation be applied to the fact that the matrix with this property is a scalar matrix? I mean: if any matrix $A$ that isn't a scalar fails to commute with _some_ element of $S$, that is $B$ in our case, then what about the rest of the elements of $S$? Maybe $A$ commutes with one of them.

Comment: Whether or not $A$ commutes with *some other* element of $S$, we've already shown that $A$ is *not* one of the matrices which commutes with *all* elements of $S$, which is what we needed to do.

Comment: $ABy_1=A(y_1+y_2)=\lambda_1y_1+\lambda_2y_2$ and $BAy_1=B(\lambda_1 y_1)=\lambda_1(y_1+y_2)$. If $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$ then $AB=BA$?

Comment: Unless $A$ is a multiple of the identity, we cannot have $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$.